# What is the Big-O of code that uses random number generators?

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o

I want to fill the array 'a' with random values from 1 to N (no repeated values). Lets suppose Big-O of randInt(i, j) is O(1) and this function generates random values from i to j.
Examples of the output are:

{1,2,3,4,5} or {2,3,1,4,5} or {5,4,2,1,3} but not {1,2,1,3,4}

```
#include<set>
using std::set;

set<int> S;// space O(N) ?
int a[N];  // space O(N)
int i = 0; // space O(1)
do {
    int val = randInt(1,N);   //space O(1), time O(1) variable val is created many times ?
    if (S.find(val) != S.end()) { //time O(log N)? 
        a[i] = val; // time O(1)
        i++; // time O(1)
        S.insert(val); // time O(log N)  <-- we execute N times O(N log N)
    }
 } while(S.size() < N); // time O(1)
```

The While Loop will continue until we generate all the values from 1 to N.
My understanding is that Set sorts the values in logarithmic time log(N), and inserts in log(N).

```
Big-O = O(1) + O(X*log N) + O(N*log N) = O(X*log N)
```

Where X the more, the high probability to generate a number that is not in the Set.

```
time O(X log N)

space O(2N+1) => O(N), we reuse the space of val
```

Where  ?? it is very hard to generate all different numbers each time randInt is executed, so at least I expect to execute N times.
Is the variable X created many times ?
What would be the a good value for X?

Comment: Figuring out the big-O of code is not as important as writing code that works/does not have an infinite loop

Comment: We also don't know anything about your random source. If it is truly random, then your worst-case X is ∞.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that the RNG is ideal. That is, repeated calls to randInt(1,N) generate an i.i.d. (independent and identically distributed) sequence of values uniformly distributed on {1,...,N}.

(Of course, in reality the RNG won't be ideal. But let's go with it since it makes the math easier.)

## Average case

In the first iteration, a random value val<sub>1</sub> is chosen which of course is not in the set S yet.

In the next iteration, another random value is chosen.

- With probability (N-1)/N, it will be distinct from val<sub>1</sub> and the inner conditional will be executed. In this case, call the chosen value val<sub>2</sub>.
- Otherwise (with probability 1/N), the chosen value will be equal to val<sub>1</sub>. Retry.

How many iterations does it take on average until a valid (distinct from val<sub>1</sub>) val<sub>2</sub> is chosen? Well, we have an independent sequence of attempts, each of which succeeds with probability (N-1)/N, and we want to know how many attempts it takes on average until the first success. This is a geometric distribution, and in general a geometric distribution with success probability p has mean 1/p. Thus, it takes N/(N-1) attempts on average to choose val<sub>2</sub>.

Similarly, it takes N/(N-2) attempts on average to choose val<sub>3</sub> distinct from val<sub>1</sub> and val<sub>2</sub>, and so on. Finally, the N-th value takes N/1 = N attempts on average.

In total the do loop will be executed

[image: 1 + N/(N-1) + N/(N-2) + ... + N/1 = N sum_{i=1}^N 1/i]

times on average. The sum [image: sum_{i=1}^N 1/i] is the N-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) which can be roughly approximated by ln(N). (There's a well-known [better approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) which is a bit more complicated and involves the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), but ln(N) is good enough for finding asymptotic complexity.)

So to an approximation, the average number of iterations will be N ln N.

What about the rest of the algorithm? Things like inserting N things into a set also take at most O(N log N) time, so can be disregarded. The big remaining thing is that each iteration you have to check if the chosen random value lies in S, which takes logarithmic time in the current size of S. So we have to compute

[image: N sum_{i=1}^N ln(i) / i]

which, from numerical experiments, appears to be approximately equal to N/2 * (ln N)^2 for large N. <del>(Consider asking for a proof of this on math.SE, perhaps.)</del> EDIT: See [this math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/268586) for a short informal proof, and the [other answer to that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/268994) for a more formal proof.

So in conclusion, the total average complexity is Θ(N (ln N)^2).
Again, this is assuming that the RNG is ideal.

## Worst case

Like xaxxon mentioned, it is in principle possible (though unlikely) that the algorithm will not terminate at all. Thus, the worst case complexity would be O(∞).

Answer (score 0):

That's a very bad algorithm for achieving your goal.

Simply fill the array with the numbers 1 through N and then shuffle.

That's O(N)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

To shuffle, pick an index between 0 and N-1 and swap it with index 0.   Then pick an index between 1 and N-1 and swap it with index 1.  All the way until the end of the list.

In terms of your specific question, it depends on the behavior of your random number generator.  If it's truly random, it may never complete.  If it's pseudorandom, it depends on the period of the generator.   If it has a period of 5, then you'll never have any dupes.

Comment: I know this is a bad algorithm, but I don't know how to analyze the Big-O.

Comment: Not answering the question. -1

Comment: The point of the question is to analyse the behaviour of a non-trivial algorithm, not to write it optimally. One may assume that the RNG is functional for the purpose of this discussion.

Comment: "functional RNG" isn't a meaningful phrase.  If you want to specify an algorithm, then it could be analyzed.

Comment: @user2143819 the code is not bad, it actually does not work.

Comment: @kfsone yeah, but the algorithm is so bad it's not worth bugfixing  -  nor was it the question.

Comment: @xaxxon it makes the answer trivial: the big-O (best, avg, worst) of this code is always infinity :)

Comment: @kfsone ah yes :)  unless N == 0

Answer (score -2):

It's catastrophically bad code with complex behaviour. Generating the first number is O(1), Then the second involves a binary search, so a log N, plus a rerun of the generator should the number be found. The chance of getting an new number is p = 1- i/N. So the average number of re-runs is the reciprocal, and gives you another factor of N. So O(N^2 log N).

The way to do it is to generate the  numbers, then shuffle them. That's O(N).

Comment: You cannot analyze the algorithm without taking into consideration the range of the random number generator.   Did you just delete your previous answer and paste it back as a new answer because you got downvoted?

Comment: No, because I missed that the search is binary. But the random number generator is O(1) and the range is known, so the code has defined behaviour and can be analysed.

Comment: It depends on the range and periodicity of the underlying algorithm -- which presumably isn't actually generating the numbers 1-N.

Comment: As I said,we can assume that the RNG is functional.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "functional RNG"

Comment: Its not bad, its non functional, it has an infinite loop.